# About the valuative criterion for complete varieties in Mumford

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In Mumford's red book $\S1.9$ he gives the valuative criterion for completeness  as

A variety $X$ is complete iff for all valuation rings $R\subset k(X)$ containing $k$ and with quotient field $k(X)$, $R\supset o_x$ for some $x\in X$.

This seems stronger than the direct corollary from the criterion for properness because it requires that the function field of $R$ should be $k(X)$. I want to ask is this correct? Or can somebody give me some references about the proof of this strong version?

Comment: This is actually equivalent, but the proof is a bit rough. See [my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3893572/hartshornes-exercise-ii-4-5c-a-third-time/3905228#3905228) - if this resolves your question, please let me know and I'll be happy to mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: @KReiser Yeah, it helps me! Thank you!